# Solving a system of linear equations with complex unknown

Tags: equation-solving, matrix

I am trying to solve the system of equations which is given by $ABA^*=-B$, where A is $2\times2$ matrix, $A^*$ is a conjugate transpose of $A$ and $B$ is a $2 \times 2$ unitary matrix. Entries of both $A$ and $B$ are some complex numbers.

I set

`A = {{a,b},{c,d}}
 AConjugate = ConjugateTranspose[A]
 B = {{i,j},{k,l}}`

And

`G = A.B.AConjugate + B`

It follows from  $B$ being unitary that 
`ConjugateTranspose[B].B` is the $2\times2$ identity matrix, which gives us the following assumptions about the entries of $B$:

`i*Conjugate[i]+ k*Conjugate[k]==1 && j*Conjugate[j]+ l*Conjugate[l]==1 && 
 i*Conjugate[j]+ k*Conjugate[l]==0 && j*Conjugate[i]+ l*Conjugate[k]==0`

I tried to use `Solve`:

`Solve[{G==ConstantArray[0,{2,2}], i*Conjugate[i]+ k*Conjugate[k]==1 && 
 j*Conjugate[j]+ l*Conjugate[l]==1 && i*Conjugate[j]+ k*Conjugate[l]==0 && 
 j*Conjugate[i]+ l*Conjugate[k]==0 },{a,b,c,d,i,j,k,l},Complexes]`

But this runs forever without spitting the solution out. The same goes for `Reduce`:

`Reduce[G==ConstantArray[0,{2,2}] && i*Conjugate[i]+ k*Conjugate[k]==1 && 
 j*Conjugate[j]+ l*Conjugate[l]==1 && i*Conjugate[j]+ k*Conjugate[l]==0 && 
 j*Conjugate[i]+ l*Conjugate[k]==0 ,{a,b,c,d,i,j,k,l},Complexes]`

Any ideas why? Am I setting this up correctly?

Comment: I have seen adding a domain spec to the end of Solve or Reduce taking vastly longer than if it just solved the problem in general and then selected those which satisfy the domain. This `Simplify[Reduce[G==ConstantArray[0,{2,2}] && i*Conjugate[i]+ k*Conjugate[k]==1 && 
 j*Conjugate[j]+ l*Conjugate[l]==1 && i*Conjugate[j]+ k*Conjugate[l]==0 && 
 j*Conjugate[i]+ l*Conjugate[k]==0 ,{a,b,c,d,i,j,k,l}],G==0]` very quickly finds you a "solution" but I question whether it is going to be in a form acceptable to you. Usually telling Mathematica to use complexes is redundant, that's often the default.

Comment: @Bill thank you!